# Cocoa powder stays stuck at the bottom of the cup

Tags: milk, cocoa, hot-chocolate

I am trying to make a warm drink using cocoa without much additions.
Basically I boil water and the slowly add it to a cup with cocoa powder while I stir. I also add some cold milk.
When I stir with a spoon, I see that it becomes sticky and liquid and looks like butter melted.
The problem is that when I fill the cup with boiling water and some cold mild and start drinking it, in the end most of the cocoa powder have stayed stuck at the bottom of the cup.
How can I make it so that it is completely dissolved but only using water and a bit of milk?
Please note, that I don't have a microwave

Comment: Are you using 100% cocoa powder, or a pre-packaged hot cocoa mix (which contains sweetener, and other additives like powdered milk and emulsifiers which allow the "just add water" instructions)?

Comment: @AMtwo: Yes 100$ cocoa powder

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa powder [does not dissolve in liquid](https://foodcrumbles.com/chocolate-milk-sedimentation/#:%7E:text=Cocoa%20powder%20particles%20do%20not,sitting%20in%20a%20fatty%20phase.), it prefers fatty liquids like milk.

You need to create a liquid think enough so that the cocoa particles stay suspended in it.

Answer (score 1):

Mix your cocoa powder with your cold milk before adding the hot liquid, while stiring.

That way most of the cocoa powder should get into the drink.

But water, cocoa powder and a little milk will not make a normal chocolate drink, for that you need sugar, or a replacement, and a lot more fat, like milk instead of water.

Your recipe would work with chocolate drink powder "just add water".

Comment: Does it matter if the milk is skimmed/low fat?

Comment: We used to use coffee creamer (so very fatty 'milk') as the starter, with sugar added. Chocolate to eat is rather fatty, so making a fat free or almost far free drink does not seem to fit.